# Same code to parse int, float, decimal?

Tags: c#, parsing

I have a method to parse `strings`. It can be used to parse a `float` using a specific `culture` and then get a new `string` with a specific out-`culture`. The same applies to `ints`, `doubles` and `decimals`.

The code that I've written is quite repetitive for each of the different parse methods which makes it hard to maintain (especially as I am just about to make the method a lot more complex).

Is it possible to make this code less repetitive?

```
if (mapping.ParseDecimal)
{
    decimal i;
    if (decimal.TryParse(value, numberStyle, inCulture, out i))
    {
        return i.ToString(outCulture);
    }
    else
    {
        if (logger.IsDebugEnabled)
            logger.DebugFormat("Could not parse value \"{0\" to a decimal using the culture \"{1}\".", value, inCulture);
    }
}
else if (mapping.ParseDouble)
{
    double i;
    if (double.TryParse(value, numberStyle, inCulture, out i))
    {
        return i.ToString(outCulture);
    }
    else
    {
        if (logger.IsDebugEnabled)
            logger.DebugFormat("Could not parse value \"{0\" to a double using the culture \"{1}\".", value, inCulture);
    }
}
else if (mapping.ParseFloat)
{
    float i;
    if (float.TryParse(value, numberStyle, inCulture, out i))
    {
        return i.ToString(outCulture);
    }
    else
    {
        if (logger.IsDebugEnabled)
            logger.DebugFormat("Could not parse value \"{0\" to a float using the culture \"{1}\".", value, inCulture);
    }
}
else if (mapping.ParseInt)
{
    int i;
    if (int.TryParse(value, numberStyle, inCulture, out i))
    {
        return i.ToString(outCulture);
    }
    else
    {
        if (logger.IsDebugEnabled)
            logger.DebugFormat("Could not parse value \"{0\" to a int using the culture \"{1}\".", value, inCulture);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If repetition is your primary concern, you could try doing something like this:

```
public delegate string ParserMethod(string value, NumberStyles numberStyle, CultureInfo inCulture, CultureInfo outCulture);

public static class NumericParser
{
    public static readonly ParserMethod ParseInt = Create<int>(int.TryParse);
    public static readonly ParserMethod ParseFloat = Create<float>(float.TryParse);
    public static readonly ParserMethod ParseDouble = Create<double>(double.TryParse);
    public static readonly ParserMethod ParseDecimal = Create<decimal>(decimal.TryParse);

    public static Logger Logger { get; set; }

    delegate bool TryParseMethod<T>(string s, NumberStyles style, IFormatProvider provider, out T result);
    static ParserMethod Create<T>(TryParseMethod<T> tryParse) where T : IFormattable
    {
        return (value, numberStyle, inCulture, outCulture) =>
        {
            T result;
            if (tryParse(value, numberStyle, inCulture, out result))
            {
                return result.ToString(null, outCulture);
            }
            else
            {
                if (Logger != null && Logger.IsDebugEnabled)
                    Logger.DebugFormat("Could not parse value \"{0}\" to a {1} using the culture \"{2}\".", value, typeof(T).Name, inCulture);
                return "";
            }
        };
    }
}
```

This way, you only have to pass around the appropriate `ParserMethod` you want to use.  In your case, you could map your different mapping values to the appropriate `ParserMethod`.  And call it when needed.

Comment: Create<int>(int.TryParse);  in what namespace is Create located?

Comment: `Create<T>()` is the static method that you see at the end of the class.  ;)  I needed a nice way to create the `ParserMethod`s and a factory fit the bill.

Comment: ahhh...I see it now, thanks.  thanks for the quick answer.

Answer (score 5):

I have a method that does something similar in that it takes a string and converts it to a given primitive type. It uses generics so there's less code.

```
    public static T ReadConfigItem<T>(string strValue, IFormatProvider formatProvider) where T : struct
    {
        T result;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strValue))
        {       
            result = (T)(Convert.ChangeType(false, typeof(T), formatProvider));
        }
        else
        {
            result = (T)(Convert.ChangeType(strValue, typeof(T), formatProvider));
        }

        return result;
    }
```

It can then be used like this:

```
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo c = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");
    Console.WriteLine(ReadConfigItem<double>("90,99", c));
    Console.WriteLine(ReadConfigItem<double>("9", c));
    Console.WriteLine(ReadConfigItem<int>("6", c));
    Console.WriteLine(ReadConfigItem<double>(null, c));
    Console.WriteLine(ReadConfigItem<int>(null, c));
    Console.WriteLine(ReadConfigItem<bool>("true", c));
    Console.WriteLine(ReadConfigItem<bool>("True", c));
    Console.WriteLine(ReadConfigItem<bool>(null, c));
```

I'm in the UK and the output I get is:

```
90.99
9
6
0
0
True
True
False
```

If you wanted you could change this to an extension method on the string class.

Example of extension class:

```
public static class ConvertExtensions
    {
        public static T ConvertTo<T>(this string strValue, IFormatProvider formatProvider) where T : struct
        {
            T result;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strValue))
            {
                result = (T)(Convert.ChangeType(false, typeof(T), formatProvider));
            }
            else
            {
                result = (T)(Convert.ChangeType(strValue, typeof(T), formatProvider));
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
CultureInfo c = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");    
Console.WriteLine("".ConvertTo<double>(c));
Console.WriteLine("True".ConvertTo<bool>(c));
Console.WriteLine("true".ConvertTo<bool>(c));
Console.WriteLine("".ConvertTo<bool>(c));
Console.WriteLine("".ConvertTo<decimal>(c));
```

Comment: This would have been the best method if I didn't have to use the Parse version :) +1 though for a really nice solution